# AJAX: POST method content is not transferred

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, client-server

I am a beginner in Client Server application. After reading several forums, I developed a basic Javascript Client with Java Server and trying to send data using POST. However when I successfully established the connection between them, on the server side when I printed the received data, It only prints the headers and not the actual data content. Like this

```
The Client /127.0.0.1:34290 is connected
The HTTP request string is ....
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 30
Origin: null
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The Client side code is :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
        {
          name: "Donald Duck",
          city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

The server side code is :

```
inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectedClient.getInputStream()));
outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectedClient.getOutputStream());

String requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
String headerLine = requestString;

StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
responseBuffer.append("<b> This is the HTTP Server Home Page.... </b><BR>");
responseBuffer.append("The HTTP Client request is ....<BR>");

System.out.println("The HTTP request string is ....");
while (inFromClient.ready()) {
// Read the HTTP complete HTTP Query
    responseBuffer.append(requestString + "<BR>");
    System.out.println(requestString);
    requestString = inFromClient.readLine();
}
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server code does not print the last line in the request (it reads it via `inFromClient.readLine()` then `inFromClient.ready()` switches to false and the last line is forgotten without being printed).

Try this (without the response stuff, just to verify that the request is complete):

```
inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectedClient.getInputStream()));

String requestString;
while ((requestString = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(requestString);
}
```

Comment: Yeah Already tried. The output was this    `Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 30
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache`